# SQL Server Linked Server to Azure SQL using Azure AD

Tags: azure-sql-database, linked-server, active-directory

I am trying to set up a linked server from an on-prem SQL Server to an Azure SQL instance.  The Azure SQL instance uses Azure AD for authentication.  When we attempt the connection we get this error
[image]

The server it can not open is the piece after the @ symbol in the typical azure ad user name ie:something@company.com

I have searched the internet for answer and I can not find any reference to used Azure AD for a linked server connection.  Is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is not possible today.

Standard [Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/windows-authentication-overview) (AD) authentication works, however [Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/overview-authentication) (AAD) is not implemented in the on-premises version of SQL Server for linked servers.

I have not tried [Active Directory Federation Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/active-directory-federation-services) Authentication (ADFS), however.

Linked servers outbound from Azure SQL Managed Instance *do* support Azure Active Directory Authentication, in [limited scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#azure-sql-managed-instance-linked-server-authentication).